# How to assign a task to a group?

Tags: java, spring, workflow, activiti

How can I assign a task to a user group in activiti. To a single user it can be done using below code.

```
taskService.setAssignee(taskId, userId);
```

But how can we assign a single task to a group, which can be picked by any user belong to that group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TaskService`:

```
      /**
   * Convenience shorthand for {@link #addGroupIdentityLink(String, String, String)}; with type {@link IdentityLinkType#CANDIDATE}
   * 
   * @param taskId
   *          id of the task, cannot be null.
   * @param groupId
   *          id of the group to use as candidate, cannot be null.
   * @throws ActivitiObjectNotFoundException
   *           when the task or group doesn't exist.
   */
  void addCandidateGroup(String taskId, String groupId);
```

When you add candidate group, you can fetch the task by:

```
  taskService.addCandidateGroup(task.getId(), "sales");
  assertNotNull(taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("sales").singleResult());
```

For more info check `org.activiti.engine.test.api.task.TaskServiceTest#testDeleteTaskIdentityLink` in activiti source.

Comment: Just to add some colour to Martin's answer (which is absolutely correct). Tasks can only be "assigned" to a single user, this is the user who is responsible for completing the task. However, if a task can be claimed by multiple users, then these users are considered "Candidates". Candidates can be set from individual users, groups or even combinations of both. Tasks that are not "Assigned" can be claimed by any registered "Candidate".

Hope this helps.